# How to see that $\text{dim}(L)=k-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> > Consider $L:=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^k: cx=\delta\right\}$ with $c=(c_1,\ldots,c_k)$ and $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\text{dim}(L)=k-1$.

Do not know how to show that.
Anyhow my first idea was to pick any $j\in\left\{1,...,k\right\}$ and then
$$
x_j=\frac{1}{c_j}\sum_{i\neq j}c_ix_i,
$$
so that for any $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)^t\in L$ it is
$$
x=x_1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\c_j^{-1}c_1\\0\\\vdots\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\ldots+x_{j-1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\1\\c_j^{-1}c_{j-1}\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}+x_{j+1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\c_j^{-1}c_{j+1}\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}+\ldots+x_k\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\c_j^{-1}c_k\\0\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So it is $\text{dim}(L)=k-1$.

But I am not sure if this is correct, because from what do I know that $c_j\neq 0$?

Comment: $L$ is the translation (in the direction of $c$) of the $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace orthogonal to $c$. So you may wanna put $\delta=0$ when computing dimension.

Comment: If $c=0$, it's either $L=0$ or $L=\Bbb R^n$. So you need $c \neq 0$, which means a non-zero $c_j$.

Comment: Ok, got it. And whether $\delta =0$ or $\delta\neq 0$ doesn't matter, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you. Then I suggest to add "Show... if $c\neq 0$. Otherwise the task isn't correct.